# Randomize a Number over multiple points in descending order

Tags: php, algorithm, statistics

I need to distribute a number for multiple points in degraded order.

For example,

```
N = 100 // this 100 is fixed
no_of_points = 10 // no of points will vary
```

Need to break 100 into 10 points in descending order **RANDOMLY**.

e.g:

`80, 55, 32, 18, 10, 10, 10, 8, 2, 0`

Here,

1. degradation will be faster towards end
2. Must contain a zero to end

I'm trying to do something like:

```
private static function generateRandomPercentage($no_of_points)
{
    $distributions = [];

    // need to start from 80
    // but it may vary also

    $max = mt_rand(80, 81);
    $ratio = $max / $no_of_points;

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $no_of_points; $i++ ) {
        $delta = ($ratio * $i);
        $distributions[] = round(($max - $delta) / 100, 2);
    }

    print_r($distributions);
}
```

But nothing working. 
Please help me.

Comment: `array_reverse (array_rand ( range(80,0) , 10 ));`

Comment: There seem to be some flaws with the randomness of array_rand(), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with php standard functions:

```
$N = 100 // this 100 is fixed
$no_of_points = 10 // no of points will vary

$distributions= rsort(array_slice(shuffle(range(1,$N)), 0, $no_of_points);
print_r($distributions));
```

range = create array with values 1...n

shuffle = shuffle array

array_slice = return part of an array

rsort = sort array values hight to low values

Comment: No getting expected result. :( because degradation is almost uniform.. but I need much random jump like: `80, 55, 32, 18, 10, 10, 10, 8, 2, 0` would you please help me with any algorithm that can help me?

Comment: So duplicate values are allowed?

Comment: What does "more random jump" actually mean? Seems to be a quite human concept, please explain it in terms of math ;-)